# After calling the SplashScreenActivity the Application minimizes

Tags: java, android

I have the following Problem: I want to create a Splash Screen, that I can call during my Game Loop (it is a "Next-Level" splash screen).

When I call the Splash Screen, it works with animation and everything but the app minimizes itself after 5 seconds. This Splash Screen call happens after the main activity was already started.

My SplashActivity looks like this:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView logo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
            }
        }, 5000);

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.viewanimation);
        logo.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

And I want to call it in my GameLoop with the following call:

```
Intent i = new Intent(gamePanel.getContext(), SplashActivity.class);
gamePanel.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

The SplashScreen opens and the animation works, but then the MainActivity should be present again (not started new).

Comment: Does the app crash after 5secs ?

Comment: It minimizes, I can focus it again, then the circle repeats, animation shows -> minimizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one  `Splash.java`

```
    public class Splash extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            Thread myThread=new Thread(){
               @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
      Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.viewanimation);
                    logo.startAnimation(anim);  
//sleep time after animation
                    sleep(3000);  
//to end the splash screen and call next activity with Intent
                    finish();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            };
            myThread.start();

        }
    }
```

In your manifest file, `Splash.java` will be your first activity to launch,

```
<activity android:name=".Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

using `finishActivity()` instead of `finish().`

`finish()` Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The `ActivityResult` is propagated back to whoever launched you via `onActivityResult().`

`finishActivity(int requestCode)` is used to finish another activity that you had previously started with `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`

Comment: I can't use startActivityForResult from context, it is not available for me. The gamePanel inherits from SurfaceView, this is where i get the `getContext()` from.

Comment: Do you do something like this on init: GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel(this) in main activity? if so, you just cast back to MainActivity: ((MainActivity)gamePanel.getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, i);

Comment: Yes! I start the GamePanel like this in the MainActivity: `this.setContentView(new GamePanel(this));`

Comment: I just tried this, now the Application gets stuck on the SplashScreen. (even after 5 seconds nothing changes)

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the Manifest? MainActivity has the category LAUNCHER and SplashActivity the category DEFAULT.